# Azure database firewall issues

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I just tried to create a database on my SQL server and managed to do it. But I get the following error:

```
The server you specified xxx.database.windows.net does not exist in 
any subscription in xxx@xxx.com. Either you have signed in with 
an incorrect account or your server was removed from subscription(s) 
in this   account. Please check your account and try again.
```

I dont have a support plan, strangely it worked couple of days ago when I created a database which I was able to connect to.

It also says check the `Microsoft.SQLServer.ConnectionDlg.core`

Comment: Are you trying to connect from code or some sort of db gui?

Comment: I'm just using the azure portal web services. From which you can configure a database in visual studio. I want to connect and open it so I can create the tables.

Comment: Check if SQL server is Visible in Azure portal under required subscription and if you are using same subscription in SQL Server.

Comment: I checked it, to be honest it seems like it's just needs some time to update. Because I didin't change anything and it just worked all of a sudden...

Answer (score 3):

Well after some investigation I came to the conclusion that it's a bugg that is in Azure. I added my IP-address in the confiugartion windows for the database in the Azure Portal, checked if SQL was visible and some other settings. All of a sudden it just started working again. I think this can be disregarded as an solvable issue.

1. Check your configuration of the database to see IP's that are allowed to connect through the firewall.
2. Check if database and SQL is visible under the SQL Server settings in Azure portal.

Comment: It's *not* a bug. Changes to firewall rules are *not* applied immediately.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you outpaced the creation of the database when you were trying to connect. The error indicates the database doesn't exist (yet).

If you started in the portal, after initiating the create database process there is some delay where your database is unavailable- provisioning is not immediate, though it is generally very quick. You will receive a notification in the portal when the creation is complete.

Additionally: You were correct in that you will need to add the IP you want to connect from to the firewall, though the text of the error is not indicating a firewall issue. [For more on Firewall Rules/Settings in Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure).

For more general reading: [Getting started with SQL on the Azure Portal.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started)

Comment: Strangely I am getting this error even though the server and database are already displayed as 'deployed' in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your IP. For me that last number in my IP changed. If it keeps changing consider to put your IP as a range